# The angle brackets notation in $A=\mathbb{Z}^3/\langle f_1,f_2,f_3 \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I am being asked to consider a group $A$, where $A=\mathbb{Z}^3/\langle f_1,f_2,f_3 \rangle$ where $f_1= (4, 0, −14)$, $f_2 = (24, 2, 60)$, and $f_3 =
(−5, 0, 20)$.

I don't know what the angle bracket notation means in this context, and as such, I can't even begin to work out what the elements of $A$ will be.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $<f_1, f_2, f_3>$ denotes the subgroup [generated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) by the elements $f_1, f_2, $ and $f_3$ (do you know what that means?)

Comment: Yes, you're correct; my latex error, sorry!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $H:=\langle f_1, f_2, f_3\rangle$ is the subgroup of $\Bbb Z^3$ of all elements generated by the $f_i$. That is to say that $H$ contains all elements that are a finite product of both the $f_i$ and/or their inverses, and no other elements.

In this context, it means that one "kills"${}^\dagger$ the $f_i$ by taking the quotient, meaning that one considers all elements of $H$ as equivalent to the identity in $A$.

---

$\dagger$: Yes, that's a technical term!